# Possible dimension of a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

1) Let C denote the set of all separable Complex Hilbert spaces that contain a fixed Hilbert space $H_0$. Is there an upper bound for the cardinality of C?

2) Suppose that $K = \{H_{\alpha}\,:\, \alpha \in I\}$ is a collection of separable Hilbert spaces with the property $\alpha \le \beta \implies H_{\alpha} \subset H_{\beta}$ and each $H_{\alpha} \supset H_0$. Also $K$ is totally ordered with respect to set inclusion. If $H$ denotes the completion of $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} H_{\alpha}$, can we say something about the dimension of the Hilbert space $H$?

Answer (score 1):

$\max\{|\mathbb{Q}|,|I|\} $

is an upper bound on the Hilbert dimension.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your first question is new and not well defined since the set of Hilbert spaces is not actually a set but a class. If you only care for isomorphism equivalence classes, then the answer is $\mathbb{Q}$. The second answer holds because $A\times B = \max\{A,B\} $ for cardinalities $A$ and $B$ if at least one of them is infinite https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.